# AWS SNS not giving mobile option

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am trying to use AWS SNS along with FCM to send push notification to my android application.

AWS [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-android-push-messaging-sns/) says:

1. Create a platform application in Amazon SNS
2. Open the Amazon SNS console.
3. Open the left navigation pane, expand Mobile, and then choose Push notifications.

But on my Amazon SNS page, I can not see Mobile in the left navigation pane.

Am I missing something?

Somewhere I read that Amazon SNS to mobiles are not supported in UK. Is it true?

Comment: The [Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) SMS Pricing - AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/) page is showing _United Kingdom_ as a valid destination.

Answer (score 6):

@George, I suspect you are using AWS region=eu-west-2(London) and the reason why you can't see the "Mobile" option is because apparently some AWS regions don't allow you to create platform application.

[AWS SNS Supported Regions for mobile applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-push-supported-regions.html)

You will need to use any of the above regions that supports the creation of SNS platform applications.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Depending upon your screen size, the left navigation pane might be hidden.

Click the "three lines" on the left side of the screen. It should expand into a menu:

[image]